# Some questions about Corda Network Permission

Tags: corda

I have some questions about Corda Network Permission. In creating a root network CA's keystore and truststore section in https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.1/permissioning.html#id6

Create a new keypair
This will be used as the root network CA’s keypair
Create a self-signed certificate for the keypair. The basic constraints extension must be set to true
This will be used as the root network CA’s certificate
Create a new keystore and store the root network CA’s keypair and certificate in it for later use
This keystore will be used by the root network CA to sign the doorman CA’s certificate
Create a new Java keystore named truststore.jks and store the root network CA’s certificate in it using the alias cordarootca
This keystore must then be provisioned to the individual nodes later so they can store it in their certificates folder.
I have three questions:

1. First question is that what is "The basic constraints extension" in your Step 2 means? Due to the code to generate the selfsignedCA is X509Utilities.createSelfSignedCACertificate(subject, caKey) and so I don't know where I can config this parameter.
2. Second one is that what is difference between " keystore" in Step 3 and "Java keystore" in Step 4? That means the first is "PEM" file and the second is "jks" file?
3. The last one is that I don't see any parameter about "alias" in Step 4.

By the way, you can give me some useful code to address those problems?

Answer (score 0):

In our Network certificate hierarchy, A Corda network has three types of certificate authorities (CAs):

1. The root network CA
2. The doorman CA
3. Each node also serves as its own CA

The required key pairs and certificates take the form of the following Java-style keystores (this may change in future to support PKCS#12 keystores) in the node’s /certificates/ folder

You can refer to the diagram for hierarchical explanation, 
[image]

Or you can find more information at: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/network/permissioning.html#key-pair-and-certificate-formats